# Databricks Error: AnalysisException: [TABLE_OR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND] The table or view `mytable` cannot be found

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-sql

When I attempt a select * from a VIEW in databricks I get the error:

```
AnalysisException: [TABLE_OR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND] The table or view `mytable` cannot be found. Verify the spelling and correctness of the schema and catalog
```

This strange because the table does exist see image below
[image]

The sql query starts off as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW mytable AS

WITH cte_Umbrellas AS (
SELECT
  ud.umbrella_name as umbrella_name,
  ud.domicile_country_code 
FROM
```

And yet I don't get any errors with the following:

```
create or replace temporary view mynewview

as 

Select * from mytable
```

Any thoughts why I'm getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot you posted is how you would query the results of a view if you've previously defined it with a CREATE VIEW statement:
SELECT * FROM  view_name;

It seems like you're trying to query the view some other way, but did not share it? Did you share the query you ran that caused the error?